# How to mimic firebase with a postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, firebase, web-applications

If one wanted to mimic firebase where changes to data are updated real time to connected clients, how could one do this?

Comment: Nothing in Firebase is magic, and we're very willing to help you figure out specifics. But building an entire service like that is hardly the stuff that fits into a Stack Overflow answer. Start with a database, add a large caching layer, add web sockets for communication, write client-side SDKs, and then at least a few dozen man years to make everything work.